# Set customize sorting reporting services

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have just create a report with reporting services. I have insert a Chart line, and throught a query, I populate this chart.

The result of the query is

```
    ---------------------
    |COLUMN 1 | COLUMN 2 |
    ----------------------
    |200      | 7.410    |
    |300      | 29.779   | 
    |400      | 29.690   |
    |600      | 8.718    |
    |Uptime   | 24.400   |
    ----------------------
```

Now, I would like to show I line with a particular order. I would like to show at first position the Uptime value and sorter the other result with Value of COLUMN 2. So the result is this:

```
    ---------------------
    |COLUMN 1 | COLUMN 2 |
    ----------------------
    |Uptime   | 24.400   |
    |300      | 29.779   |
    |400      | 29.690   |
    |600      | 8.718    |
    |200      | 7.410    |
    ----------------------
```

This is a Chart Now

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below to the bottom of your query?

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN COLUMN2 = 'UPTIME' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, COLUMN2 DESC
```